# Calculate reading time of a highly fragmented file (random read) from HDD

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems, computer-architecture

Having hdd specifications:

```
Manufacturer
    

Toshiba

Disk Family
    

MQ-01ABD100

Features
    

Silent Seek technology, shock sensor, Silent HDD, Advanced Format technology, S.M.A.R.T.

Bytes per Sector
    

4096

Disk Interface
    

SATA 3 Gb/s

Buffer Size
    

8192 KB

Connector Type
    

7 pin Serial ATA

Form Factor
    

2.5" x 1/8H

Capacity
    

1 TB (1 x 1 000 000 000 000 bytes)

Number Of Disks
    

2

Number Of Heads
    

4

Spindle Speed
    

5400 RPM

Hard Drive Type
    

internal hard drive

Average Seek Time
    

12 ms

Max Seek Time
    

22 ms

Track-to-Track Seek Time
    

2 ms

Average Latency
    

5.55 ms

Data Transfer Rate
    

300 MB/seconds

Width
    

69.85 mm (2.75 inch)

Depth
    

100 mm (3.94 inch)

Height
    

9.5 mm (0.37 inch)

Weight
    

117 g Max

Compatibility
    

Game console, PC, TV, Recorder and External storage

Min Operating Temperature
    

41 °F

Max Operating Temperature
    

131 °F

Humidity Range Operating
    

8 - 90%

Sound Emission
    

23 dB

Shock Tolerance
    

400 g @ 2ms half-sine pulse (operating) / 900 g @ 1ms half-sine pulse (non-operating)

Mode
    

Active

Value
    

4.5 W

Required Power For Spinup
    

940 mA

Power Required (Seek)
    

2.7 W

Power Required (Idle)
    

1.0 W

Power Required (Standby)
    

0.25 W

MTTF(Mean Time to Failure: Actual operating life of the product may be different from the MTTF)
    

600,000 hours

Seek Errors
    

1 per 10^6

Non-Recoverable Errors
    

1 per 10^14
```

Need to calculate how long will take approximately Reading a highly fragmented 10GB file (random read) from this HDD

The answer is >1hour.
Can someone explain how to calculate the given result?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This sounds like a school question. The first problem is that this is a very rudimentary look at a more nuanced problem. It’s currently unsolvable because we are not provided the file system format which should include cluster size/block size, nor are we given the percentage of fragmentation, nor the ratio of random to sequential reads. However approaching this at a very rudimentary level it is ((avg seek time in sec + avg latency in sec) * seeks) + (byes read / avg transfer rate in Bytes per Sec).

Comment: Note that ‘seek’ count cannot be calculated without the information that is missing. So it’s unknown what estimate is expected by your instructor to derive an actual answer for this equation.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume random positioning of consecutive fragments (more often true than not), you can add *number_of_fragments * average_seek_time* to the unfragmented, sequential throughput time. That simple formula gives surprisingly accurate estimates.

The "data transfer rate" in your table is the interface speed (buffer to interface) and that only applies to previously buffered/cached data. Instead, you'd need the sustained disk-to-buffer rate. That *media rate* varies from the beginning of the disk (100%) to the end (some 60%) due to *zone bit recording*.

Toshiba doesn't specify the rate for that drive. A disk of that rate and age I'd estimate at 100-60 MB/s, with an average of 80 MB/s. A 10 GB unfragmented file would read in something like 125 seconds. "Highly fragmented" is what? 64 KB per fragment? Add 10,000,000,000/65,536 * 12 ms or 1800 seconds. 32 KB per fragment doubles that to an hour.

Before anyone shouts "pure theory" - I've tried this approach many times. Just run it in your lab.